# why my function is not working in another function in vue 3 axios in laravel?

Tags: function, vue.js, axios, reload

I made this `getData` function to fetch the data from database, now I am calling this function in my add, update and delete function so I don't have too refresh every time after a click. Calling this function is working in the delete function but not in the add and update. Why?

I am trying to call the function the same way as I calling it in the delete function but it is not working for the add and update function

```
    <script>
    let App = ({

        data() {
            return {
                add_numbertype: {
                    'id': null,
                    'name': null,
                    'character': null,
                    'created_by': null,
                    'updated_by': null,
                    'transaction_id': null,
                    'user': null,
                    'status': null
                },

                dataList: [],

            };
        },
        created() {
            this.getData();
        },
        methods: {
            //function for fetching data
            getData() {
                axios.get('/data').then((response) => {
                    this.dataList = response.data.result;
                })
            },
            //end
            //function for adding data
            addNumbertype() {
                
                    axios.post('/add', this.add_numbertype)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            if (response.status === 200) {
                                document.getElementById("add-form").reset();

                                $('#createModal').modal('hide');
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Add',
                                    'New record added Successfully',
                                    'success'
                                )
                                this.getData();
                            } else {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        }).catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(error.response);
                        })
                
            },
            //end
            //function for deleting data
            deleteData(id) {
                axios.get('/delete/' + id).then((response) => {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Deleted!',
                        'Your file has been deleted.',
                        'success'
                    )
                    this.getData();
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                })
            },
            //end
            //to show data in modal for update
            editData(list) {
                this.add_numbertype = {
                    'id_u': list.pn_id,
                    'name_u': list.pn_name,
                    'character_u': list.pn_character,
                    'updated_by_u': null,
                    'transaction_id_u': list.transactions_id,
                    'user_u': list.user,
                    'status_u': list.status
                }
            },
            //end
            //to update data
            updateData(id) {
                
                    axios.post('/update/' + id, this.add_numbertype)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            if (response.status === 200) {
                                $('#updateModal').modal('hide');
                                document.getElementById("update-form").reset();
                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Update',
                                    'New record updated Successfully',
                                    'success'
                                );
                                this.getData();
                            }

                        }).catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(error.response);
                        })
                
            },

        },
    });
    Vue.createApp(App).mount('#add');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code in the addNumbertype method. In the .then function of the axios post request, this does not refer to the Vue component instance, but instead refers to the function scope. This means that this.getData will not work as expected and will result in a TypeError. To resolve this issue, you can use an arrow function instead to preserve the value of this. Here is the corrected code:

```
addNumbertype() {
  axios.post('/add', this.add_numbertype)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("add-form").reset();
        $('#createModal').modal('hide');
        Swal.fire(
          'Add',
          'New record added Successfully',
          'success'
        );
        this.getData();
      } else {
        alert("error");
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
}
```

Additionally, there's also an issue in the updateData method where this also refers to the function scope and not the Vue component instance. The same solution can be applied here as well, use an arrow function to preserve the value of this. Here is the corrected code:

```
updateData(id) {
  axios.post('/update/' + id, this.add_numbertype)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        $('#updateModal').modal('hide');
        document.getElementById("update-form").reset();
        Swal.fire(
          'Update',
          'New record updated Successfully',
          'success'
        );
        this.getData();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response);
    });
}
```